# Vector fields that make up a local frame are continuous

Tags: differential-geometry, smooth-manifolds, vector-fields, orientation, tangent-spaces

In Lee's book *Introduction to Smooth Manifolds*, on the section on orientations, he notes that

> Recall that by definition the vector fields that make up a local frame are continuous

which I did not fully understand. If we are given a set of vector fields $X_1, \ldots, X_n$, then them being a local frame on some open set $U$ of a manifold $M$ means that for each $p \in U$, $\{X_i\}$ forms a basis for $T_pM$. How is continuity implied from this definition?

In fact, in Tu's book *Introduction to Manifolds* he explicitly mentions that the vector fields may be discontinuous:

> A frame on an open set $U \subset M$ is an $n$-tuple $(X_1, \ldots, X_n)$ of possibly discontinuous vector fields on $U$ such that at every point $p \in U$, the $n$-tuple $(X_{1,p}, \ldots, X_{n,p})$ of vectors is an ordered basis for the tangent space $T_pM$.

Comment: maybe in the definition of local frame its implied the continuity of the coordinate systems

Comment: @Masacroso You mean Lee may have defined a frame as consisting of strictly continuous vector fields?

Comment: yes, Im saying that. However reading the book it seems that this is a mistake in Lee's book, as it distinguishes smooth frames from rough (non-smooth) frames, so I guess that Lee forget to say **smooth** local frame, instead of just local frame

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The vector field defined on Chapter 8 (page 174) is a ***continuous*** map from $M$ to $TM$.

> If $M$ is a smooth manifold with or without boundary, a vector field on $M$ is a section of the map $\pi$: $TM\rightarrow M$. More concretely, a vector field is a **continuous** map $X$: $M\rightarrow TM$ with the property that $\pi\circ X ={\rm Id}_M$

And therefore the vector fields of the local frame defined on page 178 are all continuous.

Also, be careful, the local frame is defined on **an open set**, otherwise the continuity of the pointwise orientation may still fail. (Mobius band can help you think of this counterexample.)

**Here are some points of definitions related to your question in Lee's book:**

Vector field ----- continuous but may not smooth (page 174)

Rough vector field ----- may not continuous and may not smooth (page 175)

Smooth vector field ----- continuous and smooth (page 175)

Local frame ----- continuous but may not smooth (page 178)

Smooth frame ----- continuous and smooth (page 178)

Lee didn't define "continuous local frames" you said, since local frames are continuous in his book.

Comment: So according to that definition, all vector fields are continuous? If so, what is the need to define a continuous frame?

Comment: Lee didn't seem to define continuous frames, but only local frames and smooth frames.

Comment: Lee also talks about "rough local frame" in page 279, without being defined previously. In any case the definitions of Lee are not good at all, as outside of his book the terms "vector field" or "local frame" doesn't imply in any way continuity nor smoothness

Comment: @Masacroso Yes, but if you want to understand the definition of continuous pointwise orientation in his book, you can only follow his previous definition :(

Comment: Thank you for including all those page references, I'm happy to know that my confusion was only a matter of definitions and not conceptual.

Comment: **Please** don't make trivial formatting edits to posts unless they are part of more significant edits. Such trivial edits waste much community time reviewing the pages that get needlessly bumped to the top of the active list (and take up sparse front-page real estate).

Comment: @BillDubuque Dubuque Sorry, I find I have obsessive-compulsive disorder. I am a perfectionist. When I see some imprecise language, I can't help editing it. But my reputation will reach 2000. By then, You will need not to review my edit.

Comment: Please do not continue doing so - it is quite disruptive to the site. The purpose of this site is *not* to gain reputation or badges. Accounts have been suspended for such behavior.

Comment: @BillDubuque Sorry for the late response. I'm asleep. I don't think it is disruptive to the site. On the contrary, I think this is not only conducive to improving the quality of the website, but also helps the questioners to make their expressions of mathematical language more precise. Most of the people who are active on this website are majored in mathematics. When these people reach a certain depth to publish papers and journals, if they can not express the most basic mathematical language rigorously, it is conceivable that their papers will be rejected even if they are published.

Comment: @BillDubuque In the next place,  when you enter the "Suggestive Editing" guidance page, the website will tell you that "even a small editor can be a good editor". When you finish an edit and write an edit summary, the website will also prompt you to "correct spelling or grammar". In your opinion, is it important to "correct spelling or grammar"? Even less important.

Comment: But you are doing so on a massive scale which is highly disruptive. This has already wasted much of my time and surely many others. If you continue to do so I will flag it your account for moderator attention. Please stop so this is not necessary.